# Task scheduling in cuba platform

Tags: scheduled-tasks, cuba-platform

What is the way to register a Bean for the scheduling system in cuba. I tried like the cuba_emailer (EmailerMBean), but i'm not able to select my bean in "administration create scheduled tasks".

Answer (score 2):

Your bean should satisfy the requirements mentioned in the [documentation](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.2/scheduled_tasks_cuba_reg.html):

*The bean is listed and available for selection only if it is defined in the core module and has an interface, which contains methods appropriate for invocation from the task. Beans without an interface are not supported.*

Most probably you should add an interface to your bean.